# href javascript limitations

Tags: javascript, href

Most people won't use javascript in href for style reasons. Fact is it appears that there are severe limitations to what you can do inside href. Unfortunately the developer console cannot help out, so I'm hoping you can. This does work:

```
     <a href="javascript:alert('high five');
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.onreadystatechange = function () {
     var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
     if (this.readyState === DONE){
     alert(this.readyState);
     }
     };
     request.open('GET', 'http://www.mototale.com', true);
     request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); 
     request.send(null);
     ">mosh mosh</a>
```

but this doesn't:

```
    <a href="javascript:alert('high five');
    var foo=document.getElementById('ko');
    function doMove() {foo.style.left =
      parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';setTimeout(doMove,20);};
    function init(){foo.style.left = '0px';doMove();};
    init();">move</a>   
    <p id="ko">ok</p>
```

and a number of variants.

Please don't advice to use onclick, or unobtrusive, that is outside the scope of this question. 
What limitations are there to `javascript:` in `href` ?

Comment: Um, what is your question?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What were you expecting and what did you get? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Putting long codes like this in the `href` seems like horrible style. Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Inject js in a 3rd party business app.

Comment: No, I got some of it to work. I guess I ought to build Firefox from source to attach a debugger to it, but when I put a style attribute in the element, it does count up (with or without () by the way).

Answer (score 1):

To call a function you need `()` after it. Change

```
init;">move</a>
```

to:

```
init();">move</a>
```

in the second version and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `init` in the second example.

```
<a href="javascript:...init();">move</a>
```